# What is the difference between the 8 GB DDR5 or 500gb RAM for the PS4?

Tags: ps4

I'm a little confused. So there is a 500gb PS4, and a 8 GB DDR5 PS4. I was wondering what the difference is and which is better?

Comment: I would say the one with larger numbers in the price tag!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 500GB is *storage* for games and the 8GB GDDR5 RAM is *memory* for the console to use.

There is no choice, either. All current PS4 systems are 500GB storage and 8GB GDDR5. All future PS4 units will be 8GB DDR5 because memory/cpu/gpu specs don't change within a console generation (with very rare, inconsequential outlives). Eventually PS4 units may have more than 500GB drives included, but currently, for built in storage, 500GB is all there is.

Answer (score 6):

The 500GB refers to the Hard Drive, while the 8GB DDR5 refers to the RAM in the system. It is not an either or, you have and need both in the system. The hard drive is used to store information (save games, videos, installs, files, etc.) whereas the RAM is used to increase the speed of the processing of the system (sort of).

All systems come with these built in when you buy it, though you can [upgrade the Hard drive](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5107/~/upgrade-ps4-hdd) if you feel brave (and know how to do it!).

Answer (score 0):

No 500gb storage just 1 gb ddr5 graphic card memory 8gb ram for speed u can upgrade the hard drive ram is used to increase the speed of the system

Comment: Can you edit this with punctuation?  This is almost completely unreadable.